# Admob does not display with Smartface 4.3 published app

Tags: admob, smartface.io

The published version of app does not show admob and gives an error on the app screen as "Missing adActivity with android:configChanges in AndroidManifest.xml"
Shoud i configure manifest to show admob?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Smartface App Studio are you using ?

SAS 4.3.0 has the correct AndroidManifest file. You just need to define AdMob and its publisher Id' on ScriptEditor.

For more information;

http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/plugins/admob/

Comment: I am using 4.3.0. Everything is ok on device emulator but if you publish it gives error on the admob area.